# howto install firefox + dependencies on debian without root privileges

Tags: firefox, debian, user

I have a problem installing Firefox without root privileges.

Mozilla says the following:

```
Firefox will not run at all without the following libraries or packages:

* GTK+ 2.10 or higher
* GLib 2.12 or higher
* Pango 1.14 or higher
* X.Org 1.0 or higher
```

Of course i need to install all these dependencies without root privileges as well, but the thing is i don't know exactly how to do this. I've tried a few things i found on the internet, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies you listed are already part of most reasonably recent Linux distros. Even Debian stable (aka lenny) already has them all. Almost all graphical programs require them, so if you have a desktop environment running, they will already be installed.

In that case, you can just grab Firefox from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all.html (choose the Linux version in your language). You'll get a .tar.bz2 archive; just uncompress it with

> tar -xjf firefox-xxx.tar.bz2

in the directory where you want to install it, e.g. in your home dir. Then you'll get a new directory "firefox". cd into it, and run

> ./firefox

That's it...

Answer (score 0):

You can build Firefox statically from sources on an uptodate debian system, get the staticaly built binaries, and try to run it on your old system.

A statically built binary means that all the lib it depends on are included in the binary itself.

Comment: There's no need to do that in general. Most distros already have all the necessary libs. Plus, building FF is not necessarily trivial...